# adding extracted content as columns in a dataframe using dplyr

Tags: r, dplyr

I have this code..extracting itemId and productId

```
url <- "http://www.exploratorystore.io/cart.do?action=addtocart&itemId=EST-12&categoryId=STRATEGY&productId=DC-SG-G02"

parameter_values <- param_get(url, c("itemId", "productId"))
```

Now,I want to store these ids in separate columns in a dataframe .how to do this using dplyr mutate fn.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you already have a dataframe it should be as simple as:

```
my_df <- my_df %>% 
    mutate(item_col = urltools::param_get(url, "itemId")[[1]],
           product_col = urltools::param_get(url, "productID")[[1]])
```

Comment: i am using     df2 = cbind.data.frame(df,parameter_values) but i want dplyr solution          I meant how i extract and store these Ids together in dataframe

Comment: Currently i am trying this : [code] > df17 = df13 %>% mutate(Item = param_get(referer,"itemId"),Product = param_get(referer,"productId"))
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : not compatible with STRSXP[/code]

Comment: Without seeing more of your code I can't say for certain what's going on. But I've edited my answer with code that seems to work and fits your description.

Comment: Ok i got itemIds in place item_col but i got NAs for all product_col rows .what to do next ? I tried this : `> df22 <- df13 %>% 
+     mutate(item_col = urltools::param_get(referer, "itemId")[[1]],
+            product_col = urltools::param_get(referer, "productID")[[2]])
Error in mutate_impl(.data, dots) : subscript out of bounds` but getting errors

Comment: Pls suggest what to next .i'll mark your comment as answer .THanks!

Comment: For `product_col` your index is incorrect. It should be `product_col = urltools::param_get(referer, "productID")[[1]]`. The function `param_get` returns a list. Since you're only asking for it to get the productID value, the list it returns is only length 1.